# PHP include path problems when using PEAR Mail on Bluehost

Tags: php, path, include, gmail, pear

I am trying to modify a TemplateMonster template that uses PHP to email data from a form.  It uses localhost as the email server by default, but my client already uses gmail's mail exchange servers and likes it that way.  I am using the code from the top answer in this question: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

I think I have it all set up pretty well, except that the host installs PEAR and PHP to a predefined folder and I am working on a subdomain.  I am getting errors about not being able to find mail.php although I have modified php.ini to try to include the correct path.  Here is my error (with a few name changes to protect privacy of my client):

[08-Nov-2012 10:52:15] PHP Warning:  require_once(../../mail.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home6/clientname/public_html/subdomainname/bin/contactFormHandler.php on line 3
[08-Nov-2012 10:52:15] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../../mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/php') in /home6/clientname/public_html/subdomainname/bin/contactFormHandler.php on line 3

And here is the tree:
/home6/clientname/php/mail.php is the file I am trying to include
/home6/clientname/public_html/subdomainname/bin/contactFormHandler.php is the file that is throwing the error

And here is my code from contactFormHandler.php that is the include:
require_once "mail.php";

I have tried various iterations such as "../../../php/mail.php" to no avail.  Any suggestions on what I need to do so that the PHP file on the subdomain can "see" the PEAR files I am trying to include?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Mail.php instead of mail.php

the filename for the PEAR package is Mail.php and Unix/Linux systems are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the error message!  I actually had it like that to begin with but for some reason I have both mail.php and Mail.php - the lowercase one is in the php folder with smtp.php and looks like just one part of the Mail package.  It's still broken but clearly this was a wrong assumption in trying to track it down - thank you and I will rep when I have enough myself to do so!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to contact Bluehost support and ensure, that Mail package is installed and available on your server.

They will also advise you on the correct relative path to Mail.php